# Magento Join Collection Tables

Tags: magento, join, collections

I'm working on a store that only has downloadable products in it. I need to get each customer's downloadable products and be able to sort them by product name and sku. My current code works in retrieving all the download links.

```
$purchasedItems = Mage::getResourceModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('purchased_id', array('in' => $purchasedIds))
            ->addFieldToFilter('status',
                array(
                    'nin' => array(
                        Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PENDING_PAYMENT,
                        Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PAYMENT_REVIEW
                    )
                )
            );
```

However, this does not return the product name nor the sku. So I am attempting a join on the collection to the `catalog_product_flat` table.

```
$productTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product_flat');
$purchasedItems->getSelect()
            ->join(array('products' => $productTableName), 'main_table.product_id = products.entity_id', array('table_alias.*'));
```

Doing a `var_dump($purchasedItems)` returns a `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Link_Purchased_Item_Collection Object`. But I cannot iterate over the `$purchasedItems`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If u use flat tables for your catalog it will work, if not you can try to join the product collection with attributes you need

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look for joining magento custom, I am using it in my project and it is working perfectly.

Syntax

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();

$collection->getSelect()->join(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'table_name_for_join', 'main_table.your_table_field ='.Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'table_name_for_join.join_table_field',array('field_name_you_want_to_fetch_from_db'));
```

Working Query Example

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_varchar', 'main_table.products_id ='.Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id',array('value'));
```

Hope this will work for you as well!

Cheers!

Comment: Any chance to post how you did it? Thanks